# Integrate Software AG Alfabet with AD, PPLUS, and JIRA

Tags: integration

I am looking to integrate Software AG Alfabet with the following services:

- Active Directory (AD) for user authentication and management.
- PPLUS (I assume this refers to a specific application or platform – replace with full name if possible) for [mention the specific purpose of integration].
- JIRA for issue tracking and project management.

Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me to the right documentation for achieving these integrations? Specific questions I have include:

1. built-in support does Alfabet have for these integrations?
2. Are there any recommended best practices for setting up these connections securely?
3. How can I synchronize data between Alfabet and these services, particularly for user accounts in AD, data from PPLUS, and issues from JIRA?

I have administrative access to Alfabet and the necessary credentials for the other services.

Thank you for your help!